# Desktop application proxy settings

Tags: apiconnect-test-monitor

I am trying the desktop application of IBM Connect Test and Monitor. Anyone knows whether it uses the system proxy? I am trying to call an internal URL, I know I can see thourough a browser, but I get "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xxxxx.yyyy.zz xxxxx.yyyy.zz:443".

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with how the request is constructed or your local DNS service. What if you try to restart your DNS service?

Comment: The request is identical to both the browser/postman and "Test and Monitor". I also cannot see any options regarding this; network settings. This is why I asked wheter it uses system settings.

Comment: To answer your question, yes the system proxy is used. The issue might be in one of the underlying libraries used by the app but cannot pinpoint the culprit at the moment.